# Android studio Firebase Services plugin not loading

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-service, firebase-assistant

Opening Firebase Services plugin in Android Studio is not working for me.
(I wanted to Record Robo Script through Firebase in Android Studio to use in Firebase Test Lab)
I am getting an exception as shown in the screenshot.

Any hints to make this work?

[image]

Android Studio version:
[image]